# What is the shape that have the biggest surface area with hypervolume of 1 in $N$ dimensional space?

Tags: geometry, dimensional-analysis

There is a theorm saying that from all shapes in $N$ dimensional space with hypervolume of 1 (in arbitrary units) $N$ dimensional ball is the one with the smallest surface area ($N$ dimensional sphere),

What is the shape from all the shapes in $N$ dimensional space with hypervolume 1 (in arbitrary units) have the biggest surface area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no upper bound to the (equivalent to) surface area for $N \geq 2$.  For instance, with $N = 2$, consider what happens as we crinkle the surface more and more vigorously:

The first is a polar plot of $\frac{1}{2\pi}(2+\sin(20 \theta))$ for $0 \leq \theta \leq 20$.  Its perimeter is $14.6\dots$.

[image: mild crinkling]

The second is a polar plot of $\frac{1}{2\pi}(2+\sin(200 \theta))$ for $0 \leq \theta \leq 20$.  It's perimeter is $127.6\dots$.

[image: more crinkling]

The third is a polar plot of $\frac{1}{2\pi}(2+\sin(2000 \theta))$ for $0 \leq \theta \leq 20$.  It's perimeter is $1273.2\dots$.  The waving back and forth is so rapid that there aren't enough pixels to show the spaces between the "petals" of the curve.

[image: much crinkling]

The last is a polar plot of $\frac{1}{2\pi}(2+\sin(20\,000 \theta))$ for $0 \leq \theta \leq 20$.  It's perimeter is $12\,732.\dots$.  Even though we cannot see any difference, this plot has ten times as many petals as the previous one.

[image: cheated: repeated previous plot]

It should be clear we can do the same sort of thing in higher dimensions, so there is no upper bound for (the analog of) surface area in higher dimensions.

[image: spherical version of above]

Comment: Wow, amazing illustration, thank you very much!

Comment: What if the body was convex?  Is there any result?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe : Consider a (hyper-)cylinder (which is convex) of unit (hyper-)volume.  As the radius is decreased, the (hyper-)surface area increases without bound.  In 2 dimensions, this is a rectangle with perimeter $4r + 2/r$, which increases without bound as $r \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Of course, excuse my temporary blindness.

Comment: Oops.  rectangle with perimeter $2(2r) + 2(1/2r) = 4r+1/r$.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such shape, for any shape with unit hypervolume, we can create another shape with unit hypervolume but more surface area. Let S be the surface area of our candidate shape. Then we can create a shape with surface area at least 2S by constructing an N-hyperprism with two ends composed of hypersquares of area S, edges between the square ends of length $\frac 1S$.